# Is there a possibility for not case sensitive Routes in li3?

Tags: php, case-sensitive, lithium

I would like to create a Route at Lithium, which matches

- /abc
- /abC
- /aBc
- and so on

So far i have something like this:

```
Router::connect('/abc', array('Example::test'));
```

Is there a possibility to change it to something uncase sensitive.

Thanks for your help, i couldn't find a thing in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
Router::connect('/{:dummy:[aA][bB][cC]}', array('Example::test'));
```

Edit: There is a nicer way to do it as well by creating the Route object by your self

```
Router::connect(new Route(array(
        'pattern' => '@^/ab?$@i',
        'params' => array('controller' => 'example', 'action' => 'test'),
        'options' => array('compile' => false, 'wrap' => false)
)));
```

If i brake out the pattern above '@^/ab?$@i'

- @ == start of regex
- ^ == start of line
- /ab == look for "/ab
- ? == optional trailing slash
- $ == end of line
- @ == end of regex
- i == make it case insensitive

And you can find more information here: 
http://li3.me/docs/lithium/net/http/Route

Answer (score 4):

The pattern param of the `Route` object allows you to define a case-insensitive pattern (as noted in the other answer by Nils).

I want to point out that you can also use `Router::formatters` and `Dispatcher` rules to achieve some case-insensitivity in general for `'/{:controller}/{:action}'` routes.  It's not perfect, but you may find it helpful:

```
use lithium\action\Dispatcher;
use lithium\net\http\Router;
use lithium\util\Inflector;

/**
 * The following Router and Dispatcher formatters keep our
 * urls case-insensitive and nicely formatted using
 * lowercase letters and dashes to separate camel cased
 * controller and action names.
 *
 * Note that actions set in the routes file are also
 * passed through the Dispatcher's rules.  Therefore, we check if
 * there is a dash in the action before lower casing it to make it
 * case-insensitive.  For most of the framework and php, case sensitivity
 * is not an issue.  However, the templates are derived from the action
 * and controller names and case-sensitive file systems will cause
 * differences in case to not find the correct template.
 *
 * This solution is not complete.  It does not account for case sensitivity
 * with controller names (because lithium's default handling doesn't touch
 * the case of it and we're not overriding the default controller handling
 * since it does at least camelize the controller).  It also doesn't account
 * for one word actions because they don't contain a dash.  What probably needs
 * happen is the Dispatcher needs a formatter callback specifically for
 * translating urls.
 */
$slug = function($value) {
    return strtolower(Inflector::slug($value));
};
Router::formatters(array(
    'controller' => $slug,
    'action' => $slug
));
Dispatcher::config(array('rules' => array(
    'action' => array('action' => function($params) {
        if (strpos($params['action'], '-')) {
            $params['action'] = strtolower($params['action']);
        }
        return Inflector::camelize($params['action'], false);
    })
)));
```